# Periodically getting output of a bash command in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am writing a gui wrapper to a bash command in python. When the bash command is run, the first 3-4 lines are constant, and the last line is overwritten to display the progress in textual format. I want to convert that progress into a progress bar into a python based gui.

How to retrieve the progress of the bash command periodically? All the other similar answers retrieve the first few constant lines, but they fail to fetch the last line which is periodically changing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the input using `process.stdout.readline()` then it won't fetch progress until entire line is printed to stdout. Instead you can just read stdout by streaming it character by character as given below

```
import subprocess
import sys
process = subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), ''):
    sys.stdout.write(c)
```